# How to read real time database array child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to read array data inside a child?

this my database

[image]

I tried get amount,image,price,title by using this method :

```
  var leadsRef = database.ref('items-ordered');
  leadsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {       
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          console.log(childSnapshot.val().cart.amount);
```

the result I'm getting (undefined)

Comment: yes it shows all items in cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cart` here seems to be an array so you would have to loop over each item in the cart.

```js
const cart = childSnapshot.val().cart

if (Array.isArray(cart)) {
  cart.forEach(item => console.log(item))
} else {
  Object.keys(cart).forEach((key) => console.log(cart[key]))
}
```

The reason why I am checking if cart is an array (or otherwise a map) can be found in [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: i got all info inside cart 0 , but i want only title and price

Comment: @AliAlsaggaf `cart.forEach(item => console.log(item.title. item.price))`